# How do I terminate the parallel process when the first one has finished in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, multiprocessing, terminate

Question: How can I stop process number 2 when process number 1 has finished?

Longer version: I made a script that multiprocesses 2 functions and I don't really know how I can stop the second process when the first process has finished.

My code:

```
def printHelloWorld(): # So this takes 5.0053 seconds to completly run
    print("Hello World.")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Hello World. (after 5 seconds)")


def printText(): # And this takes 10.0102 seconds to completly run
    print("Some text.")
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Some text. (after 10 seconds)")


if __name__ == "__main__": # I multiprocessed these 2 functions to reduce time. 
    # But what I actually want is to terminate process 2 when process 1 has finished.
    p1 = Process(target = printHelloWorld) 
    p2 = Process(target = printText)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()          
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

I tried a while loop to check when `p1.is_alive == False` then I should terminate process 2, but it didn't work. I also searched for answers but I didn't find any that matched my requirements.

Thank you for reading/answering!

Let me clarify some things: I am sorry if I couldn't explain it properly but what I am trying to ask is, How can I check which one has finished first and terminate the second process since it's no longer needed?

Example: what if we do not know the execution time of function 1 and 2 (both functions are in a parallel process). So once the first process has stopped, I want the other to stop to. How can I do that? I hope this is now described clearly. Sorry again for the confusion!

Comment: You do not need a while loop - waiting for `p1` to finish is exactly what `p1.join()` will do for you - and it does it *without* busily consuming CPU while it is waiting.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You can *literally* [``terminate()``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) ``p2`` after ``p1`` is done - i.e. ``p2.terminate()`` after ``p1.join()``.

Comment: Read about [`multiprocessing.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing%20event#multiprocessing.Event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you utilize [Pebble](https://pythonhosted.org/Pebble/) library. It wraps Python’s standard library threading and multiprocessing objects. But it has the excellent possibility to **cancel running calls**.

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import wait, FIRST_COMPLETED
from pebble import ProcessPool

def printHelloWorld():  # So this takes 5.0053 seconds to completly run
    print("Hello World.")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Hello World. (after 5 seconds)")


def printText():  # And this takes 10.0102 seconds to completly run
    print("Some text.")
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Some text. (after 10 seconds)")


if __name__ == "__main__":  # I multiprocessed these 2 functions to reduce time.
    with ProcessPool(max_workers=2) as pool:
        f1 = pool.schedule(printHelloWorld)
        f2 = pool.schedule(printText)
        done, not_done = wait((f1, f2), return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
        for f in not_done:
            f.cancel()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `Process.terminate`?

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process


def printHelloWorld(): # So this takes 5.0053 seconds to completly run
    print("Hello World.")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Hello World. (after 5 seconds)")


def printText(): # And this takes 10.0102 seconds to completly run
    print("Some text.")
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Some text. (after 10 seconds)")


if __name__ == "__main__": # I multiprocessed these 2 functions to reduce time.
    # But what I actually want is to terminate process 2 when process 1 has finished.
    p1 = Process(target = printHelloWorld)
    p2 = Process(target = printText)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.terminate()  # terminate process 2
    p2.join()
```

Comment: Hi! Yes I did, but check my edit again. Sorry for not explaining it in a clear way.